# parallel fan-in meaning (parallel programming)

Tags: parallel-processing, terminology

What means a "parallel fan-in"?

Context:

> A parallel reduction performs this operation in parallel, typically by performing a parallel fan-in, under the assumption that the entries can be generated and reduced in any order

Field: parallel computing

Thanks

Comment: Have you asked this on stack overflow?

Comment: z7sg, but it is about meaning of word, not about programming.

Comment: @osgx Can you give more information about where you found this term? Was it in a book?

Comment: Following discussion with fellow mods from other sites, I am migrating this to SO.

Comment: It is a scientific paper. http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&safe=off&q=%22%20parallel%20fan-in%22&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=ws  "A light-weight API for portable multicore programming"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fan-in is simply sending signals to all available inputs. It's used in electrical engineering, but also in batch processing, and obviously parallel computing.

A parallel fan-in is somewhat redundant, but in general the idea is that you are setting a large number of computational units work more or less simultaneously, i.e. all the bits of an image get sent to a GPU at once for processing.

Answer (score 4):

A [fan-in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan-in) is a reference to the number of inputs of a logic gate.

In context of your source, the meaning of *parallel fan-in* could be deconstructed as "two logic gate inputs operating in parallel".

Comment: This paper is not about hardware but about software

Comment: @osgx Sure. The answer could still apply to software. Logic gates are not always physical; they may also refer to the algorithmic properties of a device or process.